# Making a div fit the view port

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the container `".works-wrap"` to fit up to the point the icon for "Check out More" is positioned at the bottom of the view port.

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/mjbmh4/8]

Just as the image shows, but so that this happens without me having to zoom out etc, this was simply to show how I wanted it.

Making the content absolute then throws out the sticky footer.

If there's a CSS or jquery method, I'm open to either.

Thanks.

Comment: Please paste jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7nry0mf4/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new cool [CSS3 viewport sized metrics](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) to achieve this.

[See this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3v9qsqxe/). I used a static `div` with the following core styling:

```
#bottom {
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

`1vh` is defined as '1% of the current viewport height'. So `calc(100vh - 100px)` in this case resolves to '100 pixels above the bottom of a single viewport height'. You can resize the bottom right panel on the fiddle interface to see the red dot consistently stick to the bottom center of the first page.

Support on viewport metrics is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), even IE9 is supported.

Comment: Happy to share the knowledge :)

Comment: That worked for the most part, but on smaller screens (I have two different sized monitors, the discs push up into the header. 

Also, the footer then appears at the top, relative to the header. Ideas?

Comment: Love this! Never seen it before, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Monkey disable the mechanism on small screens using [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).